# Exchange Web Services Authentication problem 401

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I try to connect to Exchange Web Services in order to get appointments of the connected user.

I am looking for a solution for a long time but I believe the problem doesn't come from the code but the configuration of Exchange.

Is there a configuration to do in Exchange to give needed permissions to Exchange Web Service ?

Here is my code:

```
    private ExchangeService Service
    {
        get
        {

            //this code doesn't change the result. I tried without this code too.
            ServicePointManager
.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;


            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("myemailaddress@ourdomain.com", "the correct password");

            //I tried this code too 
            //service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "the correct password", "domain");

            service.Url = new Uri("https://mailhost.capronpodologie.com/EWS/Exhcange.asmx");


            var info = service.ServerInfo;
            return service;
        }
    }



    private CalendarFolder FindNamedCalendarFolder(string name)
    {
        FolderView view = new FolderView(100);
        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
        view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
        view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;

        SearchFilter sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.FolderClass, "IPF.Appointment");

        //Here, i have the error, 401 not authorised.
        FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = Service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, sfSearchFilter, view);
        return findFolderResults.Where(f => f.DisplayName == name).Cast<CalendarFolder>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Allways the same result, 401 not authorised.

I tried the Microsoft Exchange Connectivity test from this address :

https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com
[image]

The test passes :
[image]
Any idea ?

Comment: is it just a typo in your code? change `Exhange` to `Exchange`

Comment: Yes, you are right! I thest it like this

Comment: The test passes! But the code still doesn't work. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? it's not clear what your problem is now

Comment: Is Basic authentication even enabled? Do you see it listed in the autodiscover XML?

Comment: Have you tried using the downlevel format for the user eg domain\username

Comment: Hi again, the problem is resolved, the system administrator has changed something in Exchange. I think there are some authorisations to do to be able to consume this web service. Many thanks.